Using Python to launch KornShell, write a command and open another program from this
I am new to python need to create a script to:
launch Kornshell
type a command "boot", a process which will take around 5 minutes.
Once complete, in the Kornshell command line, open another program by typing "dgn"
Send another command to this new program which will have opened, e.g. F2
I would like to have some sort of text box appear telling the progress of the script to the user.
PASS or FAIL
Close
Can anyone guide me in the right direction of what I should be reading up on or if anyone has a similar script, can explain it to me?
Thanks
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe']) #change this to kornshell?


sounds like you might want pexpect
